# Sharepoint Hosted App : Loop through all list items using site workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, workflow-activity

I have to iterate through all list items for specific list using site workflow in sharepoint hosted app. My list is on app web.Based on Task Status column value of each list item ,I have to send email to assigned user.But I can't found any way to iterate all list item. I can't use rest API, because list is on app web.
Please suggest me, how could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the loop activity available in 2013?

Comment: No, I can't find loop activity. I used LookUpSPList activity. But I can't find the way to get all list items.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: But my list is on app web,They specified complete url for rest call,how could I achieve this for app web url.